# How to install abaqus 2022 on ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04

I try to install Abaqus 2022 on Ubuntu 22.04 in order to

https://github.com/franaudo/abaqus-ubuntu

```
./StartGUI.sh: 4: typeset: not found
CurrentMediaDir initial=""
./StartGUI.sh: 6: typeset: not found
./StartGUI.sh: 8: [[: not found
./StartGUI.sh: 10: [[: not found
CurrentMediaDir="/home/burak/Downloads/DS.SIMULIA.Suite.2022.Linux64-SSQ/DS.SIMULIA.Suite.2022.Linux64/1/"
./StartGUI.sh: 19: typeset: not found
Current operating system: "Linux"
./StartGUI.sh: 8: /home/burak/Downloads/DS.SIMULIA.Suite.2022.Linux64-SSQ/DS.SIMULIA.Suite.2022.Linux64/1//inst/common/get_DSY_OS.sh: [[: not found
./StartGUI.sh: 16: /home/burak/Downloads/DS.SIMULIA.Suite.2022.Linux64-SSQ/DS.SIMULIA.Suite.2022.Linux64/1//inst/common/get_DSY_OS.sh: [[: not found
/usr/bin/lsb_release
./StartGUI.sh: 4: /home/burak/Downloads/DS.SIMULIA.Suite.2022.Linux64-SSQ/DS.SIMULIA.Suite.2022.Linux64/1//inst/common/init/Linux.sh: [[: not found
DSY_OS_Release="CentOS"
./StartGUI.sh: 14: /home/burak/Downloads/DS.SIMULIA.Suite.2022.Linux64-SSQ/DS.SIMULIA.Suite.2022.Linux64/1//inst/common/init/Linux.sh: [[: not found
DSY_OS="linux_a64"
DSY_LIBPATH_VARNAME="LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
./StartGUI.sh: 31: /home/burak/Downloads/DS.SIMULIA.Suite.2022.Linux64-SSQ/DS.SIMULIA.Suite.2022.Linux64/1//inst/common/get_DSY_OS.sh: [[: not found
./StartGUI.sh: 46: /home/burak/Downloads/DS.SIMULIA.Suite.2022.Linux64-SSQ/DS.SIMULIA.Suite.2022.Linux64/1//inst/common/get_DSY_OS.sh: [[: not found
CheckPrereq was skipped DSY_Skip_CheckPrereq=1
./StartGUI.sh: 26: /home/burak/Downloads/DS.SIMULIA.Suite.2022.Linux64-SSQ/DS.SIMULIA.Suite.2022.Linux64/1//inst/common/linux_a64.installos: Permission denied
```

there are too many arguments to solve this problem. can you help me please. thanks

Comment: It's likely failing for the reason mentioned [here](https://github.com/franaudo/abaqus-ubuntu#run-setup) i.e. that it expects `/bin/sh` to be bash - however, rather than force-symlinking /bin/sh, you might consider changing the script's shebang to `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I solved the problem to give permission to allow execution to linux_a64.installos and the sh files that the error code contains. Finally I installed Abaqus but I get several problems also.